# virsh "live" vs "current" domain

Tags: libvirt, documentation, virsh

From [the virsh manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/libvirt-clients/virsh.1.en.html), under `attach-interface`:

> If `--live` is specified, affect a running domain.  If `--config` is specified, affect the
>       next startup of a persistent domain.  If `--current` is specified, affect the current domain
>       state.  Both `--live` and `--config` flags may be given, but `--current` is exclusive.  When no
>       flag is specified legacy API is used whose behavior depends on the hypervisor driver.

I still don't understand the difference between the "live" and "current" options—how is the "running domain" different from "the current domain state"?

Comment: **Current** means as it is on the disk, while **Live** means as it is while in a running state.

Answer (score 3):

`--current` means: If the VM is offline, use `--config`. If the VM is running, use `--live`